# how to access methods from my class inside javascript in Nashorn

Tags: java, javascript, nashorn

In Nashorn it is possible to access predefined classes of java ,

```
 var ArrayList = Java.type('java.util.ArrayList');
 var list = new ArrayList();
 list.add('a');
 list.add('b');
 list.add('c');
```

Like wise it is possible to access my classes in java script , If so how can it be done and should i be adding my jar in the classpath for referencing it ????

```
 var ArrayList = Java.type('com.example.exa');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use the `-classpath` option of `jrunscript` or `jjs`.

> -cp, -classpath (-cp path. Specify where to find user class files.)

The Java class:

```
package de.lhorn.so;

public class Foo {

    public final static int ZERO = 0;

    public static int i() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Compile it:

```
$ javac de/lhorn/so/Foo.java
$ tree de 
de
└── lhorn
    └── so
        ├── Foo.class
        └── Foo.java
```

Use it:

```
% jrunscript -cp .
nashorn> var Foo = Java.type("de.lhorn.so.Foo")
nashorn> Foo.ZERO
0
nashorn> Foo.i
[jdk.internal.dynalink.beans.SimpleDynamicMethod int de.lhorn.so.Foo.i()]
nashorn> Foo.i()
1
```