# how to specify the CLASSPATH for for jjs/Nashorn javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, classpath, nashorn

i want to load a 3rd party class in my Nashorn javascript which runs as a excitable shell script.i check the thread below but got no hint.

**how to access methods from my class inside javascript in Nashorn**
[how to access methods from my class inside javascript in Nashorn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23102103/how-to-access-methods-from-my-class-inside-javascript-in-nashorn)

here is my script

```
#!/usr/java/default/bin/jjs -scripting

var db_url = "jdbc:sqlserver://1.2.3.4:1433;databaseName=email;user=email;password=email;";
var user = "email";
var pass = "email";

var conn = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(db_url,user,pass);
var stmt = conn.prepareStatement("select version()");
var rs = stmt.executeQuery();

while(rs.next()){
    var name = rs.getString(1);
    println("version=" + name);
}
rs.close();
stmt.close();
conn.close();
```

get this error while runing

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for
>   jdbc:sqlserver://1.2.3.4:1433;databaseName=email;user=email;password=email;
>           at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:382)
>           at jdk.nashorn.tools.Shell.apply(Shell.java:381)
>           at jdk.nashorn.tools.Shell.runScripts(Shell.java:310)
>           at jdk.nashorn.tools.Shell.run(Shell.java:166)
>           at jdk.nashorn.tools.Shell.main(Shell.java:130)
>           at jdk.nashorn.tools.Shell.main(Shell.java:109) Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for
>   jdbc:sqlserver://12.3.4:1433;databaseName=email;user=email;password=email;
>           at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
>           at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
>           at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleImpl$BindCaller$T/802581203.invoke_V(MethodHandleImpl.java:960)
>           at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$jdbc_test.runScript(./jdbc-test.js:7)
>           at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.invoke(ScriptFunctionData.java:498)
>           at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.invoke(ScriptFunction.java:206)
>           at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:378)
>           ... 5 more

Comment: Try the `-classpath` switch - [jjs documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jjs.html)

Comment: both「#!/usr/java/default/bin/jjs  -scripting --classpath /opt/sqljdbc4.jar」and「#!/usr/java/default/bin/jjs --classpath /opt/sqljdbc4.jar  -scripting」do not work

Comment: Try jjs -J-Djava.class.path=<my_path> - this will make sure 'java' sees the classpath (as well as jjs)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to including the JDBC driver jar in the classpath, you must load the driver class so that it will register with JDBC.

```
#!/usr/bin/env jjs -scripting -J-Djava.class.path=/usr/local/java/sqljdbc-1.1.1320.0.jar

// jjs requires -- to start passing arguments to the script in Java 8u40b12

if ($ARG.length < 4) {
  print("Usage: ${__FILE__} -- server database user password");
  exit(1);
}
var server = $ARG[0],
    database = $ARG[1],
    user = $ARG[2],
    pass = $ARG[3];

var db_url = "jdbc:sqlserver://${server}:1433;databaseName=${database};";

java.lang.Class.forName('com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver')

var conn = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(db_url,user,pass);
var stmt = conn.prepareStatement("select version()");
var rs = stmt.executeQuery();

while(rs.next()){
    var name = rs.getString(1);
    println("version=" + name);
}
rs.close();
stmt.close();
conn.close();
```

What was missing was the call to `classForName(String)` before attempting to create the connection.