# Running Java from Nashron JavaScript - Exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, javascript, nashorn, nodeclipse

I have runMyJava.jjs (to run Java from within JavaScript using Nashorn)

```
var javaClass = Java.type('mypackage.MyJavaClass'); 
javaClass.hello();
```

to run

```
package mypackage;

public class MyJavaClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello from MyJavaClass.main ");

    }

}
```

but I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mypackage.MyJavaClass
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:382)
    at jdk.nashorn.tools.Shell.apply(Shell.java:381)
    at jdk.nashorn.tools.Shell.runScripts(Shell.java:310)
    at jdk.nashorn.tools.Shell.run(Shell.java:166)
    at jdk.nashorn.tools.Shell.main(Shell.java:130)
    at jdk.nashorn.tools.Shell.main(Shell.java:109)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mypackage.MyJavaClass
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
```

when running from Eclipse/Enide Studio or within terminal `jjs runJava.jjs`

All project is at https://github.com/paulvi/JavaRoot

Answer (score 0):

I should have run passing classpath

```
jjs -cp ./ runJava.jjs
```

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jjs.html

and the Java should be already compiled

```
javac *.java
```

[how to access methods from my class inside javascript in Nashorn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23102103/how-to-access-methods-from-my-class-inside-javascript-in-nashorn)